# On IONIC Ion-Select is 'selecting' all options on choice

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

On my Ionic app, I have a ion-select:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Type</ion-label>

  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="type" interface="action-sheet">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let type of types" 
                  value="type.class">
                  {{type.name}}
      </ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

And everytime I choose an option it selects all options avaiable.
I alredy try to use the attribute multiple="false" but didn't worked.

Extra details:

> **type.class** is the same value for every option. I already put diferent values for each option. None worked.
>   If I totally remove the *value=""* it work properly

Any help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since your value assignments are dynamic, you need to use `[]` around the `value` like,

```
<ion-option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type.class">
  {{type.name}}
</ion-option>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there a resource you can cite on this? Trying to understand the reason why the brackets make a difference.

Comment: @sparkyShorts please check out this [section](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview).

Comment: Much appreciated !

Comment: @amal I have the same issue. But it doesn't work for me. Can you help? The code is: `<ion-option *ngFor="let subtrip of trips" [value]="subtrip.tripid"> {{subtrip.startTime}} </ion-option>`

Comment: @leilei please post your full code and mention what is not working for you. It may not be a evident what the problem is just by looking at this code. May be post another question. If this solution is not working, it may not be related.

Comment: @amal Thanks for feedback. I have solved it. seems is my typing mistake causes the issue. I just retyped as your comment and ionic tutorial and it works know.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!